# Pass a constructor argument to a static block

Tags: java, constructor, static, static-block

I have a class like this

```
public class CustomRestClient {

private static String dbString;

public CustomRestClient(String db) {
    this.dbString = db;
}

static {       
    try {
        Client.setServer(Client.Server.LOCAL);
        AuthenticationProvider provider = new AuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setCredentialsProvider(new SimpleCredentialsProvider("user", "pass", dbString, "secretkey"));
        Client.setAuthenticationProvider(provider);
        Client.login();
    } catch (ClientException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    CustomRestClient customRestClient = new CustomRestClient("db");
 }
}
```

I'm trying to  pass the constructor argument inside the static block

```
provider.setCredentialsProvider(new SimpleCredentialsProvider("user", "pass", dbString, "secretkey"));
```

For example, `CustomRestClient customRestClient = new CustomRestClient("db");` should set the `dbString` field inside the static block to `db`. But when I run the program it says the `dbString` field is null. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong

Comment: the static block runs before the constructor is executed. what you are trying to do isn't possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[static block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) is executed before you create the `CustomRestClient` object

You should move the static block to static method and call it

```
public static void login(String db) {
        Client.setServer(Client.Server.LOCAL);
        AuthenticationProvider provider = new AuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setCredentialsProvider(new SimpleCredentialsProvider("user", "pass", dbString, "secretkey"));
        Client.setAuthenticationProvider(provider);
        Client.login();
}
```

And call it:

```
CustomRestClient.login("db")
```

Or (without static) move the method inside a constructor with String argument

```
private String dbString;

public CustomRestClient(String db) {
    this.dbString = db;
    try {
        Client.setServer(Client.Server.LOCAL);
        AuthenticationProvider provider = new AuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setCredentialsProvider(new SimpleCredentialsProvider("user", "pass", dbString, "secretkey"));
        Client.setAuthenticationProvider(provider);
        Client.login();
    } catch (ClientException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Now, I have more idea on how static block works.

Comment: It should be pointed out that the final option is generally frowned upon. Since doing work, especially calling static methods, inside the constructor makes a class very hard to test.

Comment: @MattWatson yes, you can call a dedicated method instead after constructor

Answer (score 1):

It's wrong to put that block of code in a static initializer block, since it depends on a constructor parameter, which is passed to the constructor after the static block is executed.

If that initialization depends on an instance specific parameter (different instances of `CustomRestClient` can receive different `dbString`s), it should be moved to an instance method (i.e. not `static`).

On the other hand, if `dbString` should remain a `static` variable, it should be initialized by some `static` method, not the constructor. In that case, your `static` initializer block should be moved to that `static` method. It would be your responsibility to execute that `static` method.

Answer (score 1):

That does not work because the `static` block runs during initialization of the class, before any instance is created or constructor runs.

And there is no way to pass parameters into that. The only thing it could do is load a static value from another place that you set up first. Reading from external configuration (system properties and such) is also an option.

You probably want to replace your static things with a singleton instance (with maybe a static method to initialize it) --- or even better a "regular" instance that you can then inject as a dependency into whatever code needs to use your `CustomRestClient` (that would make it easier if you ever need to work with multiple sets of connection settings).